# Launch People Picker in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewdidload, peoplepicker

I want to launch the contacts list people picker as soon as my app has finished loading, but the obvious thing doesn't seem to be working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    name.hidden = NO;
    name.text = @"ViewDidLoad";

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
      [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

The UILabel named "name" is getting set appropriately, but the people picker doesn't show.
I've got a button hooked up to instantiate the people picker when it's pressed, and that works fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewDidLoad is not a good place for showing anything since your view is still not ready to be shown. Call it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I chose to put it into viewDidAppear instead, but your suggestion lead the way. :)